# Managing Transaction for .NET + Salesforce API

Tags: .net, salesforce

I have .NET application that updates Database and Salesforce through API. I need to update multiple Salesforce Objects.

Code look like this

```
public class Service ....

public void myTransaction(..){
DBConnection dbcon;
SFConnection sfcon;

// DB Begin Transaction

//Update Database tables 
//Update SF Objects 

// DB End Transaction

}
```

Please help me to get better idea on how to achieve transaction.

Comment: Do you query using SOQL? While executing a SOQL query in apex you can specify 'for update' at the end of a query to keep records locked, however I would doubt transactions are available via the API due to the potential to leave records locked while an interaction times out etc.

Comment: Yes, We are using SOQL also. Here I am looking to update the data.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but for reference to those who surf on in:

Like LaceySnr hinted, transactions are not properly available (as of 2016) through the API.  There are, however, two ways to achieve transaction-like results via the API.

1. by creating a custom REST endpoint in Apex, or
2. by using the AllOrNone header with the API.

### REST Endpoint

To create a custom REST endpoint you would create an apex class defined with @RestResource.  Within that class you'd define a function decorated with @HttpPost that takes a list of sObjects.  Within the function you would set a savepoint.

When this new endpoint is called, if there a catchable error you can rollback on your own.  Otherwise, Salesforce, upon successfully completing the function, will auto-commit. In other words, you don't have to explicitly commit the transaction.  See [this documentation for creating REST endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST). and developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm for transaction control (I can't post more than 2 links).

example apex:

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/myendpoint/*')
    global with sharing bool class MyFirstRESTController {

       @HttpPost
       global static boolean doSomething(List<sObject> objectsToUpdate) {
           boolean error = false;
           Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

           //do something

           //oh no! there was an error
           if( error ) {
                Database.rollback(sp);
           }
           return error;
       }
    }
```

with that example, if you posted to /services/apexrest/myendpoint/doSomething/  with all of your sObjects it should call that function and give you some transactional control (e.g. convert the objects to JSON and post them).  You'll need to use the "Authorization: Bearer *sessionId*" header on your call to the custom REST endpoint.  The sessionId can be the same sessionId retrieved from a SOAP login (in case you use the wdsl to generate a service).

### AllOrNone Header

For the AllOrNone header see the [documentation for the SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_allornoneheader.htm).  This header allows you to indicate that if any single record fails at updating, then they all fail.  Essentially, if one record fails, the entire transaction is rolled back.

Comment: This is also a good technique for web services as well.  Esp if it's a very complicated process or you're creating multiple records.  AND, I've found it's easier to update SF than it is to redeploy .NET to all of the users w/ a particular integration.  (Keep the business logic on the server!)